# Custom glossary as part of a chapter

Tags: chapters, glossaries

I want to set a glossary as part of specific chapter. This is a sample code which I want to put `Top-Level Domains` glossary as part of `Test` chapter:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}
%Alternative glossary (for describing top-level domains in networking)
\newglossary[tlg]{domain}{tld}{tdn}{Top-Level Domains}
\makeglossaries
\makeindex

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test}

\newglossaryentry{domain:com}{type=domain, name=com, description={Commercial
entities}}
% Use the terms
Top-level domains include \gls{domain:com}.
% Print the glossaries
\printglossary[type=domain]
\end{document}
```

But as this image shows, `Top-Level Domains` glossary is not part of `Test` chapter and seems as a distinct part:
[image]

While I want to get something like this (image is edited by GIMP and is not casted from a real PDF file):

[image]

Is there a way for doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `glossaries` package options `section` and `numberedsection` to get it like your desired image (assuming you want the dotted line):

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[toc,numberedsection,section]{glossaries}
%Alternative glossary (for describing top-level domains in networking)
\newglossary[tlg]{domain}{tld}{tdn}{Top-Level Domains}
\makeglossaries
\makeindex

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test}

\newglossaryentry{domain:com}{type=domain, name=com, description={Commercial
entities}}
% Use the terms
Top-level domains include \gls{domain:com}.
% Print the glossaries
\printglossary[type=domain]
\end{document}
```

Using just `section` gives this:

[image]